# How to format report?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a table with 2 columns: Name and Age. I want the report not to be in column format but has:

```
Name (Age)
```

That means Name followed by Age enclosed in parentheses.
How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put the following in the source property for e.g. textbox control:
=[Name] & " (" & [Age] & ")"

Comment: Just a hint for better formatting, in case the Age field is not fully populated: using the `+` operator for concatenation will propagate Nulls, so `=[Name] & " (" + [Age] + ")"` will not have empty parens if Age is Null.